# How to trigger <Authorizing> state of <AuthorizeView> in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

Given this flow:

```
        <AuthorizeView>
            <Authorized>
                Welcome @context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName)?.Value
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="logout">
                    <span class="oi oi-account-logout"></span> Log Out
                </NavLink>
            </Authorized>
            <NotAuthorized>
                <Login/>
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
                <text>Please wait the system is authorizing your credentials</text>
            </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeView>
```

In my subclassed auth state provider, I am doing this

```
//logged in successfully
NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new ClaimsPrincipal(
        new ClaimsIdentity(JwtParser.ParseClaimsFromJWT(token),
          "jwtAuthType"))));
```

```
//logged out
NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()))));
```

They both work fine. Now I want to set the state to "Authorizing". What do I do?

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) mentions the Authorizing state as a valid state, but not explicitly how to trigger it.

Doing this:

```
//starting to log in
NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult<AuthenticationState>(null));
```

does indeed trigger the "Authorizing" state in the UI, so a "null" AuthenticationState does seem to be what blazor is expecting. However, it throws an exception on the front end even though it works as expected otherwise. Passing any kind of ClaimsPrincipal, causes either "Authorized" or "NotAuthorized", but never "Authorizing".

This is the exception triggered for that attempt

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthorizeViewCore.OnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
d.printErr  @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
d.preRun.push.window.Blazor._internal.dotNetCriticalError   @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
w   @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @   dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
do_icall    @   00aba242:0x194e4e
do_icall_wrapper    @   00aba242:0x79df9
interp_exec_method  @   00aba242:0x44ad3
interp_runtime_invoke   @   00aba242:0x12efff
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @   00aba242:0x118e5f
do_runtime_invoke   @   00aba242:0x79d42
mono_runtime_invoke_checked @   00aba242:0xf65d
mono_runtime_try_invoke_array   @   00aba242:0x10e831
ves_icall_InternalInvoke    @   00aba242:0xed492
ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw    @   00aba242:0xecf57
do_icall    @   00aba242:0x194ddb
do_icall_wrapper    @   00aba242:0x79df9
interp_exec_method  @   00aba242:0x44ad3
interp_runtime_invoke   @   00aba242:0x12efff
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @   00aba242:0x118e5f
do_runtime_invoke   @   00aba242:0x79d42
mono_runtime_try_invoke @   00aba242:0x12982
mono_runtime_invoke @   00aba242:0x10ec2b
mono_wasm_invoke_method @   00aba242:0x108e48
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @   dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
call_method @   dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
(anonymous) @   dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
beginInvokeDotNetFromJS @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
h   @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
e.invokeMethodAsync @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
invokeWhenHeapUnlocked  @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
t.dispatchEvent @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @   blazor.webassembly.js:1
e.onGlobalEvent
```

I also tried

```
      var authenticatingStateTask = Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(null));
      NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(authenticatingStateTask);
```

This time it doesn't even trigger the  state, and a different exception is encountered.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'user')
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'user')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState..ctor(ClaimsPrincipal user)
   at VisualService.Portal.Authentication.PortalAuthStateProvider.NotifyUserAuthenticating() in C:\projects\RemoteMonitoringNEW\EverythingIsInHere\SourceCode\ClientApps\VisualService.Portal\Authentication\PortalAuthStateProvider.cs:line 42
   at VisualService.Portal.Authentication.AuthenticationService.Login(String username, String password) in C:\projects\RemoteMonitoringNEW\EverythingIsInHere\SourceCode\ClientApps\VisualService.Portal\Authentication\AuthenticationService.cs:line 41
   at VisualService.Portal.Pages.Login.ExecuteLogin() in C:\projects\RemoteMonitoringNEW\EverythingIsInHere\SourceCode\ClientApps\VisualService.Portal\Pages\Login.razor:line 32
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
d.preRun.push.window.Blazor._internal.dotNetCriticalError @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
w @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
_mono_wasm_invoke_js_blazor @ dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
do_icall @ 00aba242:0x194e4e
do_icall_wrapper @ 00aba242:0x79df9
interp_exec_method @ 00aba242:0x44ad3
interp_runtime_invoke @ 00aba242:0x12efff
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @ 00aba242:0x118e5f
do_runtime_invoke @ 00aba242:0x79d42
mono_runtime_invoke_checked @ 00aba242:0xf65d
mono_runtime_try_invoke_array @ 00aba242:0x10e831
ves_icall_InternalInvoke @ 00aba242:0xed492
ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw @ 00aba242:0xecf57
do_icall @ 00aba242:0x194ddb
do_icall_wrapper @ 00aba242:0x79df9
interp_exec_method @ 00aba242:0x44ad3
interp_runtime_invoke @ 00aba242:0x12efff
mono_jit_runtime_invoke @ 00aba242:0x118e5f
do_runtime_invoke @ 00aba242:0x79d42
mono_runtime_try_invoke @ 00aba242:0x12982
mono_runtime_invoke @ 00aba242:0x10ec2b
mono_wasm_invoke_method @ 00aba242:0x108e48
Module._mono_wasm_invoke_method @ dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
call_method @ dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
(anonymous) @ dotnet.5.0.5.js:1
beginInvokeDotNetFromJS @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
h @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
e.invokeMethodAsync @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
invokeWhenHeapUnlocked @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
t.dispatchEvent @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
e.onGlobalEvent @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
Show 6 more frames
```

Answer (score 0):

### First and foremost:

I am **NOT** as good explaining as the udemy courses I used. This is a [link to Felipe Gavilan's youtube video](https://youtu.be/8CEeeHBXTk0?t=266) where explains the  tag and how to trigger and test it. My answer is not so loosely based in his code. Felipe Gavilan's video is in spanish, but the code is in english anyway, so I do believe you can follow along.

[This youtube video by Patrick God](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OclPAk50n6A) is a full explaination of the authorizarion logic you are having trouble with, but he does not touch upon the focus of your question.

Both of them have udemy courses that I strongly recommend.

The code in this answer is my implementation of a mix of both of their methods.

That said, here we go:

## How I did it and how to test:

### 1 dependencies and services

install the nuget packages and add them to the _Imports.razor in the client project.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
```

Add the services to the ConfigureServices(...) method in Program.cs

```
private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
           
            services.AddAuthorizationCore();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>(); //see point 2
...
}
```

### 2 methods

Now, the custom auth state provider method, which does the trick you are looking for:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(2000); //USE THIS DELAY TO TEST!
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var state = new AuthenticationState(user);
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));
        return state;
     }
...
}
```

### 3 front end components

In app.razor I just layed out the skeleton like so:

```
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <Authorizing>
            <span>Espere mientras se revisan las credenciales de acceso...</span>
        </Authorizing>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <Login />
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeRouteView>
</Found>
<NotFound>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p>Lo siento, no hay nada en esta direcci&oacute;n</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</NotFound>
```

### --->This is enough to trigger the `<Authorizing>` state.<---

But, you will now be wondering how to expand this to the login and logout methods with jwt:

If you can, go check the udemy course I pointed out, or:

I use a LocalStorageService to store the token and access it globally (seen this in many tutorials as the standard, altough I'm sure others will comment this and prove me wrong).

The `GetAuthenticationStateAsync()` Method will look like this:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;
        private readonly HttpClient _http;

        public CustomAuthStateProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorageService, HttpClient http)
        {
            _localStorageService = localStorageService;
            _http = http;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000); //I kept this, yeah.
            string authToken = await _localStorageService.GetItemAsStringAsync("authToken");
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(); 

            _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
            {
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(ParseClaimsFromJwt(authToken),"jwt");
                _http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authToken);
            }
            var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var state = new AuthenticationState(user);

            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));
            return state;
        }
```

This has a very elegant advantage:

the login method can simply be something like:

```
public async void Login(string username, string password)
{
    bool validLogin = goToDataBaseToCheckUser(username,password);
    if(validLogin)
    {
        string token = CreateToken(user);
        await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("authToken", token);
        var authstate = await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        // ¯\_ (ツ)_/¯ idk, show a message or something.
    }
}
```

and logout:

```
private async void Logout()
{
    await LocalStorage.RemoveItemAsync("authToken");
    await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
}
```

This leaves the `NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged()` calls in a single place, gives you control of the app through the token, and keeps the method calls readable, as they always should be.

I DO hope this helps.

cya.